# perl - Extract data using grep and sed

Tags: perl, sed, grep, html-parsing

I'm using this code to get all titles from urls with `http://something.txt`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$output = `cat source.html | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | grep -E 'txt' | sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | sed -e 's/<a .*title="//' | cut -f1 -d '"'`;

print("$output");
```

When i run this on perl i get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

The error is related with this portion of code:

```
sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g'
```

Comment: where you actually mentioned the file name?

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's not the problem...

Comment: I don't see any perl in your code.  [What are you really trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: @ghoti i've just added all the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In backquotes, Perl uses the same rules as in double quotes. Therefore, `\n` corresponds to a newline; you have to backslash the backslash to pass literal `\` to the shell:

```
`sed -e 's/<a /\\n<a /g'`
```